# Getting exception while deploying Spring MVC application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC. i have below project structure.

[image]

Below are classes:

ContactController.java:

```
@Controller
public class ContactController extends MultiActionController {

    @Autowired
    private ContactService contactService;

    public ModelAndView list(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
        modelMap.addAttribute("userList", contactService.listContact());
        modelMap.addAttribute("user", new Contact());
        return new ModelAndView("contact", modelMap);
    }


    public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Contact user) throws Exception {
        contactService.addContact(user);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }




}
```

ContactDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(contact);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Contact> listContact() {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Contact")
                .list();
    }

    public void removeContact(Integer id) {
        Contact contact = (Contact) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
                Contact.class, id);
        if (null != contact) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(contact);
        }

    }
}
```

Contact.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="USER_NAME")
    private String userName;
//with setters and getters
}
```

ContactServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {

    @Autowired
    private ContactDAO contactDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        contactDAO.addContact(contact);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Contact> listContact() {

        return contactDAO.listContact();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void removeContact(Integer id) {
        contactDAO.removeContact(id);
    }
}
```

hibernate-cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="net.viralpatel.contact.form.Contact" />
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

contact.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
.even {
    background-color: silver;
}
</style>
<title>Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form action="add.htm" commandName="user">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form:form>
<c:if test="${fn:length(userList) > 0}">
    <table cellpadding="5">
        <tr class="even">
            <th>Name</th>

        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user" varStatus="status">
            <tr class="<c:if test="${status.count % 2 == 0}">even</c:if>">
                <td>${user.userName}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.contact" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

web.xml entries:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

redirect.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% response.sendRedirect("user/list.htm"); %>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Spring3HibernateMaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spring3HibernateMaven</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description></description>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate3</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate annotation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.Beta1</version>
</dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->

    <!-- dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
      <version>20030825.183949</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
  </properties>
  <repositories>


        <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>

    </repositories>


  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

But once it is packaged and deployed into tomcat i am getting below exception on tomcat console:

```
 SEVERE: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
    h name 'contactController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested e
    xception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not a
    utowire field: private net.viralpatel.contact.service.ContactService net.viralpa
    tel.contact.controller.ContactController.contactService; nested exception is org
    .springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with n
    ame 'contactServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exc
    eption is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not aut
    owire field: private net.viralpatel.contact.dao.ContactDAO net.viralpatel.contac
    t.service.ContactServiceImpl.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework
    .beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactDAOI
    mpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.spring
    framework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private
     org.hibernate.SessionFactory net.viralpatel.contact.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionF
    actory; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/transaction/T
    ransactionManager;..............................................................Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not au
towire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory net.viralpatel.contact.dao.Co
ntactDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 Ljavax/transaction/TransactionManager;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.j
ava:507)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject
(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java
:283)
        ... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/transaction/TransactionManager
;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProc
essor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProc
essor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.jav
a:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFacto
ry.java:798)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:827)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:769)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:686)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.j
ava:478)
        ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.TransactionManage
```

Am i missing anything here? Please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/transaction/TransactionManager`;

Just put [Java Transaction API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jta/index.html) (`jta.jar`) into your `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: i added. But of no use. i am getting below exception while deploying.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'contactDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cou
ld not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory net.viralpatel.conta
ct.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.be
 defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: I
f init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf
/cglib/proxy/CallbackFilter

Comment: You have many JARs missing in your classpath. This time it is `cglib-proxy`. You'll have to find them one by one and add them.

Comment: If you have a lot of JARs in your system but don't know which one contains a class such as `net/sf /cglib/proxy/CallbackFilter`, you can use my tool [cf.jar](http://www.adarshr.com/papers/classfinder) for finding them out.

Comment: Adarsh Now deployment is fine. But i am getting 404 error after entering below url. is my redirect.jsp correct? url: http://localhost:8282/Spring3HibernateMaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/user/list.htm

Comment: Also, i have below warning in tomcat console.WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Spring3HibernateMaven-0.0.
1-SNAPSHOT/user/list.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
Jun 13, 2012 9:30:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHand
lerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Spring3HibernateMaven-0.0.
1-SNAPSHOT/user/list.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
Jun 13, 2012 9:30:25 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHand
lerFound

Comment: You should accept this answer and post new questions for your other issues.